# How does Apache Flink restore state from checkpoint/savepoint?

Tags: apache-flink, stream-processing

I need to know how Apache Flink restore its state from checkpoint, because I can't see any difference between the time of start and seeing first event in operator when running pure job verses restoring from savepoint.

Does state load lazily from checkpoint/savepoint?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on your use case? In general the state is loaded on job start with savepoint.

Comment: @DawidWysakowicz does it load all of the states from savepoint as it starts or it loads them as needs them(lazy loading)?

Comment: As @alpinegizmo said it depends on the state backend chosen. RocksDB keeps the state in bytes all the time and serializes/deserializes on access. HeapStateBackend deserializes on job start.

Comment: @DawidWysakowicz what about filesystems?

Answer (score 3):

The keyed state interfaces are designed to make this distinction transparent. As Dawid mentioned, the state is loaded during job start. Note that what it means to load the state depends on which state backend is being used.

In the case of operator state the `CheckpointedFunction` interface has this method

```
public void initializeState(FunctionInitializationContext context)
```

where the context has an `isRestored()` method that lets you know if you are recovering from a failure. See the [docs on managed operator state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/state/state.html#using-managed-operator-state) for more details, including an example.

Comment: What about Keyed State? They load lazily as the first key reach them or not, Flink loads all of them as it start then the stream begins?

Comment: It depends; this is an implementation detail of each state backend. Based on what I know about how they work, my guess is that the heap-based state backends load all the state into memory during job restart, and the RocksDB state backend copies state from the checkpoint into its working set (i.e. from the distributed filesystem to the local filesystem). What is it about your use case that makes you care about this detail -- are you concerned about downtime during restarts?

Comment: Hi  @DavidAnderson: What if downtime during restarts is a concern? Is there any way to enable lazy loading using RocksDB? (Query HDFS based on current key, and then cache that entry locally for future updates)