# Does Flink Know When It Has Been Restarted Without Application State?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using the AWS Kinesis Data Analytics managed version of Flink to run an IOT service. While ideally I try my best to never restart an application sometimes breaking code changes happen and I have to start the Flink app with allowNonRestoredState or in a worst case scenario I have to clear the state completely and run without state. *Is there a parameter that I can check within my Flink application to determine if I have restarted the application without any state?*

Why do this at all?

I'm essentially trying to get around the cold start problem I see where in cases of restarting the application without state I notice that the outputs from the Flink app are wrong which I believe is due to the fact the app can only replay the information present in my Kinesis stream. If I knew these records were influenced by the restart then I could mark them invalid before sending them out my app.

Edit:

- Checkingpointing is enabled
- Using a RocksDB Backend

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you enable checkpointing or not ?

Comment: You could use the interface described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48569148/2000823.

Comment: Follow up question @DavidAnderson, the docs state this interface is for non-keyed state. Is there a keyed state equivalent?

Comment: No, there is not. It may work to go ahead and implement the CheckpointedFunction interface anyway, but if not, you could introduce a dummy (non-keyed) operator that does this in order to learn what's going on, and then sends this information downstream wherever you need it.

Comment: Got it. Essentially throw an operator at the front of the job graph that essentially acts as hasBeenRestartedWithoutState and then does some sort of specialized logic to handle non restored cases. Thanks! I'm going to do a pro and con list for the additional insight and determine if it is worth the modifications.